# Is it possible to redirect system-beeps to the normal audio?

Tags: linux, audio

When I run this script I don't here any beeps - I suppose it is because there is no speaker attached to the mainboard.
Is there a way to redirect this beeps to the "normal" audio?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$|++;
my $beep = "\07";

print $beep;
sleep 2;
print $beep;
sleep 2;
print $beep;
```

Comment: I'm unsure, but I suspect the handling of the [Bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) is terminal emulator-specific... If you're using Perl, however, there might be [other](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=beep&mode=all) [ways](http://search.cpan.org/~giulienk/Audio-Beep-0.11/Beep.pod).

Answer (score 2):

Load the `snd-pcsp` module to route beeps to the [Alsa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) subsystem. This module is [blacklisted](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=448425) [by](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/14958) [many](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=481979) distributions because it can be annoying. Comment out `blacklist snd-pcsp` from `/etc/modprobe.conf` or `/etc/modprobe.d/*`.

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer, but I didn't find `snd-pcsp` on my system (openSUSE 12.1) so I couldn't test this solution.